# Stored Procedure Performance Tuning

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I got project where I need to do improve performance of the application. To improve performance I have did following changes in the application & sql Stored procedure:

1. I have replaced all temp tables to sub-queries in the stored procedure
2. Calling SP once instead of calling multiple times do to insert multiple  parameters to table one by one. (Note: created XML file with all parameters data and sent to new Stored procedure where I am doing insert parameters data to table using cursor)

Am I doing/following right way?

Answer (score 0):

Something you should take note of; If you are linking any tables in your select, be sure to use JOINS instead of selects inside selects, this may seem like a minor thing to do, but this type of change could cut your procedure's run time in half.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing temp. tables with subqueries can actually make the performance worse, because that can cause the same statement to be executed hundreds of times, instead of filling the temp table once.

Also blindly just removing procedure calls and replacing it with XML handling and cursor can be a big step backwards.

Instead of asking us if this is the correct thing, you should really measure it.

And in addition to that, you should look into the normal places for performance tuning:

- Indexing: Look at statistics io output for selected queries or plan cache for overall I/O usage
- Blocking: If something is blocking your statements, you should definitely see if there's something that can be done
- Expensive operations in query plans: Sorts, Spools, key lookups with large number of executions.

Answer (score 0):

[Performnce tuning Link](https://youtu.be/t2R0-xcKw44)

Show Execution Plan
https://statisticsparser.com/

SET Statistics IO,TIME ON in query and copy paste the messages from output window to https://statisticsparser.com/ in readable format.

1. Create Non- Clustered Index for all Columns that are used in Where
   Clause
2. Add SET NOCOUNT ON
3. Add With No Lock on all tables used in Query
4. Add Non Clustered With Include for all columns in where clause
5. Do not include functions in Join or in Where Clause
6. CTE instead of SubQuery
7. Select only required columns